# How to reduce time complexity when getting the length of the smallest divisible string between two given strings?

Tags: java, string, time-complexity

I am trying to solve a coding problem and am having trouble with Time Complexity.

Problem:

Find whether a given string 's' is divisible by string 't'. If it is divisible, find the length of the smallest string 'x' such that if 'x' is concatenated any number of times, we get both 's' and 't'. If this is not possible return -1. Find the length of the smallest string 'x'.

A string 's' is said to be divisible by string 't' if string 't' can be concatenated some number of times to get string 's'.

---

Example #1:

s = 'bcdbcdbcd'
t = 'bcdbcd'

If string 't' is concatenated twice, the result is 'bcdbcdbcdbcd' > s. String 's' is not divisible by string 't', so the result is -1.

---

Example #2:

s = 'bcdbcdbcdbcd'
t = 'bcdbcd'

If string 't' is concatenated twice, the result is 'bcdbcdbcdbcd' = 's'. String 's' is divisible by string 't'. The smallest string 'x' that can be concatenated to create both strings 's' and 't' is 'bcd'. Its length is 3.

---

```
//My Code:
String smallest = Arrays.stream(s.split(regex(""))
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    x -> firstRepeating(t, x) ? x + x : x, 
    LinkedHashMap::new, 
    Collectors.counting()))
    .keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.joining());

     if((s.length() % t.length()) == 0){
        System.out.printf("%s is divisible by %s%n", s, t);
       }

  System.out.println("The smallest string is " + small);
```

Comment: Are Strings `s` and `t` always multiple concatentations of the same smaller string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding, here is what I came up with.  You can also substitute your own data to test.

Assumptions:

1. Both Strings are a concatenation of the same smaller substring.
2. Thus, one will divide the other if the remainder (`%`) operator returns zero
   when dividing their lengths.

```
    static Random r = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int seed = r.nextInt();
            String t = generate(3,7,seed);
            String s = generate(7,11,seed);

            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < s.length()/2; i++) {
               if (s.regionMatches(0,s,i,i)) {
                  index = i;
               }
            }
            int index = 0;
            for (int idx = 1; idx < s.length()/2; idx++) {
              if (s.regionMatches(0,s,idx,idx)) {
                index = idx;
              }
            }
            String small = s.substring(0,index);

            // Check to make certain this isn't just a repeated character.
            small = small.replaceAll("^(.)\\1+$", "$1"); 
            boolean isDivisible = s.length() % t.length() == 0;
            System.out.printf("%s is " + ((isDivisible) ? "" : "NOT") 
                 + " divisible by %s%n",
                        s, t);

            System.out.println(
                    "The smallest string is " + small + "\n");
        }

    }

    static String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    public static String generate(int s, int e, int seed) {
        r.setSeed(seed);
        String stem = IntStream.range(3, 8).mapToObj(i -> {
            int len = r.nextInt(26);
            return alphabet.substring(len, len + 1);
        }).collect(Collectors.joining());
        return stem.repeat(r.nextInt(e)+s);
    }
```

Comment: Good catch!  I think I fixed it with an alternative to using a map.  But I do not know how well it will perform.